# Installing FLTK on Xcode 5

Tags: c++, xcode, fltk

Is there anyone who can give me an tutorial on how to install FLTK on Xcode 5. All my attempts have been without any luck. We have to use the program at my school.

I've been trying to load the frameworks in Xcode but when I am write:

```
#include <FL/Fl.H>
```

or

```
#include "FL/Fl.H"
```

It does not find the header file.

Mads

Comment: You need to install it first as it's not on Mac OS X, using something like homebrew/macports/manually which will provide you with an installed copy that can be referenced using the `User Header Search Paths` and `Library Search Paths`, as well as referencing the fltk library(/ies) in the `Linked Frameworks and Libraries`. fltk not building on 10.9 is a known bug - looks like a trivial change should address it.

Comment: Have you tried loading up the xcode4 build from the distribution in xcode5?