# Setup Xcode and FLTK

Tags: c++, xcode, fltk

Errors I get when trying to build the [first block of code on this page](http://www.fltk.org/doc-1.1/basics.html) under Xcode

> Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
>
> "fl_define_FL_SHADOW_LABEL()", referenced from:
>
> ```
>  _main in main.o
> ```

I installed FLTK with homebrew by `brew install FLTK` and there were no errors:

`/usr/local/Cellar/fltk/1.3.2_1: 315 files, 5.8M, built in 93 seconds`

I realize this problem has been [asked before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22372228/installing-fltk-on-xcode-5), but the answer

> You need to install it first as it's not on Mac OS X, using something like homebrew/macports/manually which will provide you with an installed copy that can be referenced using the `User Header Search Paths` and `Library Search Paths`, as well as referencing the fltk library(/ies) in the `Linked Frameworks and Libraries`

did not work for me or I got the specific *file paths* wrong. I have tried Xcode 5.1.1 and 6.0 and both have the same problem.

I have attached a screenshot of my build settings.
[image: Build Settings on Xcode]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have found the solution at [groups.google.com](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/ppp-public/jNTx7tNh7z8/qQZbowrSlv0J) and below is what I have done:

1. Change build settings as such:

   Header Search Paths : `-I/usr/local/include`

   Library Search Paths : `/usr/local/lib`

[image: Search Paths]

2. Go to terminal and type `fltk-config --ldflags`

   You get a line of flags, mine was
   `-L/usr/local/Cellar/fltk/1.3.2_1/lib -lfltk -lpthread -framework Cocoa`.

   In Xcode Build settings, paste that in `other linker flags`

[image]

3. After these steps Xcode compiled the file successfully.

Comment: For me what was missing was the User Header Search Paths part. Nice job! ;)